# Is it \catcode or \catcode`?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

I've noticed that `\catcode` is poorly documented in the TeXbook.  The primitive is defined as `\catcode` but every time it is used, it is used as `` \catcode` `` ... the backquote is never discussed. `` ` `` itself is not active (right?) so I don't understand its function. Is it required for `\catcode` to work properly?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The backquote notation is discussed in the TeXbook, page 44.

`\catcode` takes as its first argument the character code of the character you want to change the catcode of. For example,

```
\catcode65=\active
```

will make ‘A’ an active character.

Instead of inserting the number ‘65’ directly, TeX allows the character code of a character to be inserted with the backtick notation you're referring to:

```
\catcode`A=\active
```

You need to escape the character if it happens to have a special catcode, though: `` `\% ``, for instance.

This backtick notation can be used wherever TeX expects a number. E.g.,

```
\number`A
```

will typeset ‘65’.

Comment: Beat me to it by moments, Will. Just to add, this *is* described in the TeXbook, page 44.

Comment: Feel free to fix up any of my clunky statements. My explaining-brain feels like mush today.

Comment: I guess it should read `\catcode'A=\active` in your example (of course with a backtick; don't know how to put a backtick into the middle of a code sample.)

Comment: Oh yes, that was quoted incorrectly. Thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: Thanks for that informative explanation.  To recap: in situations where TeX is looking for a number, it will interpret ` as "the character code of the next character".  You have to admit, sometimes it's hard to navigate the TeXbook!