# What is the use of putting the grave accent after \catcode?

Tags: tex-core

Can someone kindly explain why is there and what is the use of the `` ` `` in `` \catcode`@=11 ``?

I came across that while I'm learning TeX from The TeXbook.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome! I'd not vote to close as duplicate as this question is better worded (for future searches) and has a good answer, but I remember [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/is-it-catcode-or-catcode) from the early days of this site :-)

Answer (score 6):

The tex syntax for a numeric literal are

```
123 % decimal
"12A % hex
'327 % octal
`@   % character value (= 64 here)
`\@  % same as above
```

so

```
\catcode`@=11
```

is the same as

```
\catcode 64=11
```

and sets the catcode of character code 64 to 11, which has the effect of making `@` a letter.